# Custom Data Frame Using Variables from Multiple Data Frames and Merging Filtered Results - Reprex Available

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr, rbind

**Goals:** To create a custom data frame that uses variables of two separate data frames. More specifically, to use a name/id variable that is found in two separate data frames, pull out specific variables associated with the name/id variable, and then customize the outputs into one row of code for evaluation and model formatting.

**Actions:** Below, I successfully, yet inefficiently used a combo of dplyr and a for loop to achieve the goal stated above. Further, I have attached photos of the steps and desired output to help understand the problem.

**Issue:** Is there an easier solution to this situation?

Below, I have two data frames that I would like to use for custom comparisons. Data frame 1 is the diamonds with state names attached. Data Frame 2 has the names I would like to compare.

The first data frame has the key variables I need to evaluate.
[image]

The second data frame has two columns of names that I want to use for comparison:

[image]

I want to use the names from the second data frame, to pull out custom variables from data frame 1, and then get them on the same row for evaluation purposes.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data frame 1 - Merge diamonds dataset w/ state names dataset
diamonds <- diamonds[1:50,]
diamonds$name <- state.name
#rearrange diamonds order
test_diamonds <- diamonds[, c(11, 1:10)]

#Data frame 2 - Create two lists for comparisons
example_names1 <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas")
example_names2 <- c("California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware")
comp_names <- data.frame(Group1 = example_names1, Group2 = example_names2)

#combine 
df = NULL
for(i in 1:4){
test100 <- test_diamonds %>%
  filter(name == example_names1[i]) %>%
  select(name, depth, price)

test200 <- test_diamonds %>%
  filter(name == example_names2[i]) %>%
  select(name, depth, price)

df <- rbind(df, data.frame(test100, test200))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Use `merge()` to avoid loops. I hope this helps.

```
#Merge
df1 <- merge(comp_names,test_diamonds[,c(1,6,8)],by.x='Group1',by.y = 'name',all.x=T)
#Merge again
df2 <- merge(df1,test_diamonds[,c(1,6,8)],by.x='Group2',by.y = 'name',all.x=T,suffixes = c(1,2))
#Arrange
df2 <- df2[,c(2,1,3:dim(df2)[2])]

    Group1      Group2 depth1 price1 depth2 price2
1  Alabama  California   61.5    326   63.3    335
2   Alaska    Colorado   59.8    326   62.8    336
3  Arizona Connecticut   56.9    327   62.3    336
4 Arkansas    Delaware   62.4    334   61.9    337
```

Comment: Great stuff @Duck! Thanks a ton. This is very helpful and makes more intuitive since than my original coding. 

Out of curiosity (and sorry for my ignorance) what is the reason for this code: 

df2[,c(2,1,3:dim(df2)[2])] 

instead of:

df2[ ,c(2, 1, 3:6)]

Comment: @DonnyDolio Great! `dim(df2)[2]` gives you the total number of columns in your dataframe. Then, if in the future you have more columns you will not have to change your code. I hope this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `apply`:

```
apply(comp_names, 1, function(x) {
  colnames = c("name", "depth", "price")
  
  cbind(test_diamonds[test_diamonds$name == x[["Group1"]], colnames],
        test_diamonds[test_diamonds$name == x[["Group2"]], colnames])
})%>%
  do.call("rbind",. )%>%
  setNames(., make.unique(names(.)))

      name depth price      name.1 depth.1 price.1
1  Alabama  61.5   326  California    63.3     335
2   Alaska  59.8   326    Colorado    62.8     336
3  Arizona  56.9   327 Connecticut    62.3     336
4 Arkansas  62.4   334    Delaware    61.9     337
```

Comment: Thank you @Dealec This code is helpful and a better alternative than my for loop. Thank you for dropping knowledge and sharing!

Comment: @DonnyDolio Glad to help ! One useful trick is to use the "." notation which refers to data frame that you're transforming.

Comment: That is a cool trick I will use moving forward. Thanks for your help!!